# 20.04.1LTS GNOME3.36.4 Unable to open desktop files when set default program as Vim

Tags: gnome

I associated plain text files with vim with right click - properties -   open with, and it works fine within nautilus, however when I click or   right click - open a text file at the desktop, vim is not called and there is either not a error message, and no other editors (like gedit)  is opened. However, right click - open with other application - choose vim works fine.

Logs from journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell:

```
gnome-shell[1267]: Could not create transient scope for PID 8605:       
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process    
with ID 8605 does not exist.                                            
                                                                        
gnome-shell[1267]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The        
clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within  
the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
```

The vim version is 8.1. (runs at the terminal and vim-gtk not installed)

It works normal before changing the default open-with settings. However, I just tried to set the associate program back to gedit, but surprisingly files on the desktop still not able to open with left click and right click - open, even I set back to gedit.

Comment: Could this be related? https://askubuntu.com/q/1310292/1157519

Comment: "but surprisingly files on the desktop still not able to open with left click and right click - open, even I set back to gedit" — however strange it may sound, for those desktop files to recover, a log out / log back in may be necessary.

Comment: @Levente Wow, that's it! Thank you. That file was copied from a NTFS storage, and that should be why it is strangely marked as executable.